# Testing CakePHP Controllers with TestAction() - Indirect Mod Error?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

#### The Situation

I'm trying to get controller unit testing started in a CakePHP2.x app. I'm referencing the docs and still getting an error with the testAction method and don't understand why or what to do.

#### Controller code:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

 class BranchLicenseApplicationsController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Session', 'Cookie', 'EntityManager');

    public function index() {
    $this->BranchLicenseApplication->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('branchLicenseApplications', $this->paginate());
     }


}
```

#### The Test Code:

```
class BranchLicenseApplicationsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

public $fixtures = array(
    'app.branch_license_application', 'app.ref_access_map'
);


 public function testIndex() {
    $this->testAction('/branchlicenseapplications/index');

 }

 }
```

#### The Output

```
 1) BranchLicenseApplicationsControllerTest::testIndex
 Indirect modification of overloaded property
 Mock_BranchlicenseapplicationsController_869bb477::$BranchLicenseApplication 
 has no effect
```

#### My Question/What I'm thinking

It seems like I'm missing something simple but I don't yet get enough to figure that out. I'm new to testing so I may not be fully grasping all of the instantiates & mocks that need to happen for controller testing.

I noticed the "Mock" in the error...but I'm not using any mocked objects. Should I be? Or am I even thinking in the right direction?

Comment: I've seen "indirect modification of overloaded property" errors when there was a bug with the object being tested.  If you haven't already, I'd try commenting out the lines inside public function index() in your controller and see what happens.

Comment: Hey @Kai thanks. I tried that & the test passed...which makes sense...but then those 2 lines seems to work just fine when calling the method via url. I don't get it...

Comment: Is debug on?  Sometimes the bug will not prevent the code from working, but will cause warnings or error messages.  Unit tests will stop on any such message.

Comment: It is - it was on 2. I bummed it up to 3 and tried again to same outcome

Comment: `.but I'm not using any mocked objects.` - Yes you are as that's how test Action works. Does the test pass removing only this line `$this->BranchLicenseApplication->recursive = 0;`, or by adding (`$this->loadModel('BranchLicenseApplication');` before it? Is that _all_ your controller code? There's probably something relevant not shown.